# How do I plot just the positive error bar with pyplot.bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot 4 average values with positive error bars and the max value within the plot.

```
means   = [26.82,26.4,61.17,61.55]         # Mean Data 
stds    = [4.59,4.39,4.37,4.38]            # Standard deviation Data
peakval = ['26.82','26.4','61.17','61.55'] # String array of means

ind = np.arange(len(means))
width = 0.35
colours = ['red','blue','green','yellow']

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.title('Average Age')
for i in range(len(means)):
    pyplot.bar(ind[i],means[i],width,color=colours[i],align='center',yerr=stds[i],ecolor='k')
pyplot.ylabel('Age (years)')
pyplot.xticks(ind,('Young Male','Young Female','Elderly Male','Elderly Female'))

def autolabel(bars,peakval):
    for ii,bar in enumerate(bars):
        height = bars[ii]
        pyplot.text(ind[ii], height-5, '%s'% (peakval[ii]), ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(means,peakval)
```

However I can can't find out how to plot only the positive error bars. 
So I end up with a graph like this:

[image: Average Age]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

means   = [26.82,26.4,61.17,61.55]           # Mean Data 
stds    = [(0,0,0,0), [4.59,4.39,4.37,4.38]] # Standard deviation Data
peakval = ['26.82','26.4','61.17','61.55']   # String array of means

ind = np.arange(len(means))
width = 0.35
colours = ['red','blue','green','yellow']

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.title('Average Age')
pyplot.bar(ind, means, width, color=colours, align='center', yerr=stds, ecolor='k')
pyplot.ylabel('Age (years)')
pyplot.xticks(ind,('Young Male','Young Female','Elderly Male','Elderly Female'))

def autolabel(bars,peakval):
    for ii,bar in enumerate(bars):
        height = bars[ii]
        pyplot.text(ind[ii], height-5, '%s'% (peakval[ii]), ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(means,peakval) 
pyplot.show()
```

Result:

[image]

It works because you can pass as `yerr` a `2xN` list, representing the positive and negative "offsets", see the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).