# Setting different errors for pandas plot bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a probability distribution using a `pandas.Series` and I'm struggling to set different `yerr` for each bar. In summary, I'm plotting the following distribution:

[image]

It comes from a `Series` and it is working fine, except for the `yerr`. It cannot overpass 1 or 0. So, I'd like to set different errors for each bar. Therefore, I went to the documentation, which is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html).

According to them, I have 3 options to use either the `yerr` aor `xerr`:

- **scalar:** Symmetric +/- values for all data points.
- **scalar:** Symmetric +/- values for all data points.
- **shape(2,N):** Separate - and + values for each bar. The first row contains the lower errors, the second row contains the upper errors.

The case I need is the last one. In this case, I can use a `DataFrame`, `Series`, `array-like`, `dict` and `str`. Thus, I set the arrays for each `yerr` bar, however it's not working as expected. Just to replicate what's happening, I prepared the following examples:

First I set a `pandas.Series`:

```py
import pandas as pd
se = pd.Series(data=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.1],
 index=list('abcdefghi'))
```

Then, I'm replicating each case:

This works as expected:

```py
err1 = [0.2]*9
se.plot(kind="bar", width=1.0, yerr=err1)
```

[image]

This works as expected:

```py
err2 = err1
err2[3] = 0.5
se.plot(kind="bar", width=1.0, yerr=err1)
```

[image]

**Now the problem:** This doesn't works as expected!

```py
err_up = [0.3]*9
err_low = [0.1]*9
err3 = [err_low, err_up]
se.plot(kind="bar", width=1.0, yerr=err3)
```

[image]

It's not setting different errors for low and up. I found an example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/errorbar_features.html) and a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312820/how-do-i-plot-just-the-positive-error-bar-with-pyplot-bar), although they are using `matplotlib` instead of `pandas`, it should work here.

I'm glad if you have any solution about that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Quanghoang comment, I started to think it was a a bug. So, I tried to change the `yerr` shape, and surprisely, the following code worked:

```py
err_up = [0.3]*9
err_low = [0.1]*9
err3 = [[err_low, err_up]]
print (err3)
se.plot(kind="bar", width=1.0, yerr=err3)
```

[image]

Observe I included a new axis in `err3`. Now it's a `(1,2,N)` array. However, **the documentation says it should be** `(2,N)`.

In addition, a possible work around that I found was set the `ax.ylim(0,1)`. It doesn't solve the problem, but plots the graph correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, `plt.bar` works as expected:

```
err_up = [0.3]*9
err_low = [0.1]*9
err3 = [err_low, err_up]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(se.index, se, width=1.0, yerr=err3)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

A bug/feature/design-decision of pandas maybe?

Comment: Thank you for answering. So, the examples that I liked works fine, just like yours. So, I'm starting to think it's a bug since the documentation says that's the way we should use.

Comment: I found a solution and it looks like a bug. Could you check my answer? Thank you!